# How to "answer" a console input prompt in PowerShell (in the code)

Tags: powershell

I am using a PowerShell command line utility from a third party software vendor. One of their cmdlets prompts for input; however, I would like to bypass this prompt by entering the value in the code rather than the input prompt. Is there a way to do this in PowerShell script?

Their cmdlet is something like this:

Set-Config

So, I've tried:

Set-Config -config "blah"

No luck.

Comment: Usually a cmdlet only prompts for input when you don't specify a mandatory (required) parameter.  Checked the help to see which parameters are mandatory and make sure you're providing all the mandatory parameters in the parameterset you're using.

Comment: To add on to Keith's comment, from what I've seen that prompt usually contains the name of the input it's looking for.  For example, typing in Get-Content prompts for "Path".

Answer (score 0):

Hrad to tell with looking at the cmdlet. By looking at your code I assume there is a Config parameter, am I right? If so, I would also look for a Force parameter and use it. Usually thr Force parameter supress confirmations.