# Using powershell to trigger an exe whilst providing arguments and automating inputs

Tags: powershell, automation, openssl, exe, command-line-arguments

We're hoping to automate the creation of certificates to simplify the process for clients.

To do this, we wanted to create a powershell script that runs through the openssl commands and autofills the inputs.

Here's an example of a command that will be run

`openssl req -new -out client.csr -key client.key`

And here's the format within the script ($loc being openssl.exe's file location)

`& $loc'\openssl.exe' @('req','-new','-out','client.csr','-key', 'client.key')`

Running this command will ask the user for several inputs, which I would like to be handled by the script.

We've tried prepending the command with `"input" |`  and  `echo input |`  as suggested in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838702/how-to-make-a-powershell-script-answer-a-prompt-for-user-input), along with different formatting of the command, but to no avail.

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/macna/793c46145c5f3899ebce5ce47176cb40#file-openssl-powershell-certgen-ps1-L56) script that feeds the inputs as a configuration file, but in testing it asked for inputs anyway

I'm new to powershell, so please be gentle if I'm making a dumb mistake :)

Comment: Why not just provide all the arguments up front?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but this [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/q/226192/139307) talks about avoiding prompts altogether.