# How to make Powershell script to Iteratively execute from multiple console and pass parameters from a CSV file for each execution

Tags: powershell, jmeter, powershell-2.0

I am required to simulate a file transfer from a location on premise to a location on the cloud or let say any other location.

I have to transfer close to 11 K files at a rate of 3 file per second and if required increase the rate of file transfer to find at what rate the system breaks

This kind of loading and throttling is easy with Jmeter OS sampler but there are issues with the sampler in my case because I am first calling an exe which is kind of parametrized and prompts for a confirmation when executed.

With Jmeter OS sampler I am not able to handle the user input and I used the correct method tested with other command to suppress the prompt.

But I think because of the EXE I am not able to suppress the prompt with OS sampler

With OS sampler it was quite easy I just had to specify the command, parametrize the file name and generate the UUID on the go and just trigger the command.

I could also control the throughput with Jmeter and control the file transfer rate, but the approach with jmeter is out of question as it simply does not work and gets stuck waiting for user input!

Towards the end I decided an approach with PowerShell script which when executed works perfectly but I am not an expert and I have created a parametrized PowerShell script as below with some guidance

```
param(
    [string]$fileName,
    [string]$uuid
      )
    $myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
    $myshell.sendKeys("y")
    $myshell.sendKeys("{Enter}")
   .\BlobFileUpload.exe .\$fileName "4f21-8c7e-45fe9b515a7f/$uuid" "routeid" "/$fileName" "inbox" <Azure Blob SAS url>

The way to execute this scrip is:- .\script-1.ps1 -uuid uuid1 -fileName file1 from the prompt
```

This code works perfectly but now I need help to pass the file name and UUID from a CSV file and a way to execute this code based on the loop count I specify and in multiple PowerShell window (for example 2 or 3 parallel execution but should pick unique file names and UUID from CSV)

Looking forward to suggestions or links to code snippets I can use to crack this one. Thanks

Comment: It feels like there's a gap of information in the very first sentence. You're working on uploading a file to the internet, but then you run into a problem with `jmeter` - what's the connection between the two? Why is it important to use jmeter to measure(?) your file upload task?

Comment: Updated the question, I hope its a bit clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a poor man's template engine.
I have written such a tool.

Here's what I mean:

Supposing you started with a template file that looks like this:

```
& .\script-1.ps1 -uuid $uuid -fileName $file
```

I'm not sure about the ampersand, but if that turns out to be unnecessary, just get rid of it.

Now suppose you had a csv file that looks like this:

```
uuid,file
uuid1,file1
uuid2,file2
uuid3,file3
```

You would use my template engine like this:

```
Expand-csv bloblist.csv bloblist.tmplt > bloblist.ps1
```

And you would produce the following:

```
& .\script-1.ps1 -uuid uuid1 -fileName file1
& .\script-1.ps1 -uuid uuid2 -fileName file2
& .\script-1.ps1 -uuid uuid3 -fileName file3
```

Now this isn't exactly what you were asking about, because this creates an expansion of the template for the entire csv file.  But maybe you could write code that reads in the entire csv file and then lets the user select a subset to write out to a smaller csv file that could be used with Expand-csv

And finally,  here is Expand-Csv itself:

```
 <#
.NOTES
    Script: Expand-Csv    Rev:  3.2
    By:     DGC           Date: 2-21-19
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates multiple expansions of a template,
    driven by data in a CSV file.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function is a table driven template tool. 

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.
#>
function Expand-csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $driver,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $template
    )
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, kind of got the idea, The piece of code you shared is another PowerShell which calls the template (which can be my powershell) to which I can pass the variables from the CSV using the Eapand-CSV.ps2 script. Let me know if my understanding is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Passing command line arguments and inputs is a feature of shell, JMeter has nothing to do about it.

I don't have powershell installed, in "normal" [CMD](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/a-beginners-guide-to-the-windows-command-line/) you can use [echo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo) command with [pipe operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in order to pass user input to the downstream commands or programs

Example:

[image]

In JMeter's OS Process Sampler you can achieve the same by using the following configuration:

[image]

If you want to parameterize the input with the values from the CSV file - go for [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) which is built into JMeter:

[image]

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838895/2897748) in powershell you can play the same trick but you won't need to invoke echo command.